# How to retrun from sql to php on successful statement

Tags: php, sql, return

I am inserting data into a table using PHP and want to find out if the SQL has worked properly so I can display a success message. Is there a way of returning success from SQL back to PHP after the statement is executed.

```
    function addPlayer($playerName, $dateOfBirth, $team) {
       $sql = "INSERT INTO players VALUES (DEFAULT, :name, :teamID, :dob)";
       $stmt = $this->connection->conn->prepare($sql);
       $stmt->bindParam(":name", $playerName);
       $stmt->bindParam(":dob", $dateOfBirth);
       $stmt->bindParam(":teamID", $team);
       $stmt->execute();
    }
```

I want to know if the execute statement has been successful and the data added to the table. Is there a way to have the SQL return a success or fail so I can display an error or success message on the page?

Comment: How do you have the `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` option set?

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: I haven't set it to anything myself so I assume it is the default value. However, I thought this was for PDO errors not returning the success of an SQL query, as a failed SQL query may not always throw a PDO error?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "failed". It's not usually an error if a `SELECT` doesn't find any matching rows, or `UPDATE` doesn't find anything to update.

Comment: No, but sometimes Insert can fail due to a wrong data type being entered or the fact that the referential integrity of the table isn't being fulfilled. This doesn't throw an error for me. Would this be the case if I changed the error handling?

Comment: The default error mode is to just return `FALSE` rather than throw an error. I suggest you enable `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` and use `try/catch` to report errors.

Comment: I'll try that and see if I can find the solution. If I am correct though this is for development only and not for the release of any software?

Comment: No, you definitely need it in production, so the script will stop if there's a problem.

Comment: Understood, Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO players VALUES (DEFAULT, :name, :teamID, :dob)";
       $connect= $this->connection->conn;
        $stmt= $connect->prepare($sql);
       $stmt->bindParam(":name", $playerName);
       $stmt->bindParam(":dob", $dateOfBirth);
       $stmt->bindParam(":teamID", $team);
       return   (   $stmt->execute()  && $connect->rowCount()>0);
```

Or shortly

```
     $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: How does this work, surely I would need to know the row count before executing this?

Comment: Is it really necessary to check `rowCount()`? The only reason why `INSERT` wouldn't insert any rows is if it gets an error.

Comment: @6C69616D It's just testing whether the row count is non-zero.

Comment: But if there is other data there already then that wont matter

Comment: If you violate a unique constraint, it will get an error, so `execute()` will return `FALSE`.

Comment: is this also the case if the referential integrity is not upheld by the new data

Comment: @6C69616D Yes. Anything that prevents the query from completing will be treated as an error.

Comment: In insert or update sometime execute method return true but SQL query not affectted none of column ...we check affected row if affected row the successful

Comment: I edited please try again ...